# 2000 Honda Accord O2 Heater error

Tags: honda, accord, cel, o2-sensor

After replacing the O2 sensor due to fault codes 1166 and 1167, I still get 1167-Heater circuit error. I check resistance through O2 sensor heat, about 17 Ohms. Plug has 14 volts feeding heater. I read somewhere that computer has to re learn parameters to get CEL to go out, after running several hours/cycles. Is this true?

Comment: Did you clear the codes after putting the new O2 sensor in?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling your comment should be an answer

Comment: im assuming he did clear the code since he said only 1167 came back.

Comment: The sensor heater Ohm reading is about right for a typical regular Oxygen sensor. It is too high for a typical Air Fuel Ration sensor. The PCM will set this code it the ohm reading is incorrect. The exact vehicle would need to be known to say for sure.  A VIN would be helpful.  There are several variations of the engine control system in these cars. Some had significant issues.

Answer (score 2):

As @FredWilson pointed out, there is no relearn for a heater circuit code.

---

On a 2.3

Check for power at the ECM connector C pin 13 (white).

On a 3.0

Check for power at the ECM connector C pin 1 (black/white).

While the o2 heater wire may have power there may be a break in the wire that goes to the ECM. This wire tells the ECM that the heater relay is working.